# xpath select first child and chek value

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to use xpath for a unit test, what I want to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api_data>
    <message>OK</message>
    <status>200</status>
    <data>
        <name>John</name>
        <email>john@gmail.com</email>
    </data>
</api_data>
```

Now I want to check if the name is `john` and email is `john@gmail.com`

xpath query: `/api_data[message="OK"]`

This works good, now the next example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api_data>
    <message><value>OK</value></message>
    <status><value>200</value></status>
    <data>
        <name><value>John</value></name>
        <email><value>john@gmail.com</value></email>
    </data>
</api_data>
```

xpath query: `/api_data[message="OK"]`

And this still matches.. But I don't want that.. so I want it more strict.. but how to?

I don't want to have a match WITH the value child, so only match without the `<value>`

Comment: `/api_data[message/value="OK"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the string value of an element in XPath is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes, i.e. all the text contained inside the element directly, or its child elements, grandchildren, etc.

So you need to check both that the string value of the `message` is "OK" *and* that the `message` does not have any child elements:

```
/api_data/message[.="OK"][not(*)]
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to do /*["OK"]

```
xpath query: /api_data/message/*["OK"]
```

Comment: I don't want to have a match WITH the value child, so only match without the `<value>`

Comment: This still doesn't match, see solution